# Google Earth Integration/ Maps V3 Flyto Onclick

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

Using the new "hackish" integration for Google Earth ( http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/ ) I have gotten this example working and worked plenty with the Google Earth plugin and V2 of Maps. I was curious as to how to access the flyto and lookat functions onclick.

Previously you could call a function like this within an anchor link and it will flyto when clicked

```
function viewSouth() {
  var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
// Set the position values
lookAt.setLatitude(28.54626988796781);
lookAt.setLongitude(-81.37704984953177);
lookAt.setRange(1070.448301908147); //default is 0.0
lookAt.setTilt(67.84202025905072);
lookAt.setHeading(-179.9640072336487);
  ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
}
```

This it seems doesnt work with the new integration method. Could I possibly get some quick instruction as to how to access this function withing the Maps V3/Google Earth Integration

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like it should work.  What kind of JS error do you get, if any? 

Can you link to a full code sample on jsfiddle or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the googleEarth variable which was set to equal GoogleEarth(map) and then it worked! thanks